# react-csv-downloader: how to download a column that has array-values into single column?

Tags: reactjs

I am using npm react-csv-downloader to download csv file. If a column has value as an array, when I open the file it will show into multiple columns.
Is there any way to put their into one column (by changing delimiter between items in that array or something similar)?

This is snippet of my code ("skills" has an array of values):

```
import CsvDownloader from 'react-csv-downloader';        

export function CreateReport(filteredArray) {
    const columns = [
      { id: "name", displayName: "Name" },
      { id: "email", displayName: "Email" },
      { id: "skills", displayName: "Skills"}
    ]
    
    return (
        <button className="btn download-report-btn">
          <CsvDownloader columns={columns} datas={filteredArray} filename="search-result">Download Report</CsvDownloader>
        </button>
    )
  }
```

Is there any way to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this way :

```
export function CreateReport(filteredArray) {
  const columns = [
    { id: "name", displayName: "Name" },
    { id: "email", displayName: "Email" },
    {
      id: "skills",
      displayName: "Skills",
      transform: (value) => value.join(", ") // join array values with a comma
    }
  ];

  return (
    <button className="btn download-report-btn">
      <CsvDownloader
        columns={columns}
        datas={filteredArray}
        filename="search-result"
        meta="true" 
        separator=";"
      >
        Download Report
      </CsvDownloader>
    </button>
  );
}
```

I hope this help. If any other queries please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It doesn't work! I also tried to use transform: (value) => value.join("- ") but the csv file still have a comma between skills.

Comment: Code-only answer, without any explanation.

Comment: Where do I have all detail props, method, .. of this library because I look at npm react-csv-downloader readme at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv-downloader and could not find above method like "transform"

Comment: @VanNguyen here you go : npm i react-csv-downloader

Comment: I get it worked finally:
<CsvDownloader
        columns={columns}
        datas={filteredArray}
        filename="search-result"
        meta="true"
        separator=";"
      >

Comment: Hi @VanNguyen , I have edited the answer and added it above so that if someone else needs a reference. They can directly access it.